# PHP include slow Website Down

Tags: php, wordpress, server-side-includes

I code alot of wordpress themes, and one thing I really like to do whenever I code them is make sure my code is very clean, organized, and easy to find things in.

One way I like to make sure my code is Organized is I like to use PHP Include like this:

`<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/top-container.php'); ?>`

So if I had a website that look like this:

```
<div class="top-container>
...
</div>
<div class="tagline">
...
</div>
<div class="slider">
...
</div>
<div class="middle-container">
     <div class="content">
     ...
     </div>
     <div class="sidebar">
     ...
     </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom-container">
...
</div>
```

My final code will look something like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/tagline.php'); ?>

<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/slider.php'); ?>

<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/middle-container.php'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So I am spiting my code into parts and including them. I love how organized my code is, but I was wondering if this was good practice? Will this slow my website down, though I am pull necessary parts?

Comment: You should look at using `include_once` or, if the include is critical to your theme to work, `require_once`. Appending `_once` will ensure that the include is only added once, even if it's included again elsewhere. Useful for functional includes.

Comment: Will it slow it down? Probably yes, since you need to open 4 files instead of 1. Is the slowdown significant? Probably not. Is it worth it? Maybe. It's not easy to answer. I'd recommend http://codereview.stackexchange.com for this type of question anyway.

Comment: I would say this is good practice. Splitting code into manageable chunks is a great way to be organised. In terms of "slowing down" the website, obviously every access to the disk counts, but this difference is very likely negligible. The important thing is maintainability.

Comment: James, for "action" includes (which do something), as opposed to "definition" includes (which define functions/classes) that is not good advice. If the same "action" is to be used twice in the request, then the *_once calls will prevent the second one from running.

Comment: thanks for all the feed back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, multiple calls to read files will produce more I/O load than a single file. You can, however, eliminate that issue using cache.

In my opinion, the best practise is whatever is easier to read, and maintain. Worry about optimization when you need to, and not before.

Answer (score 0):

you should come up with alternative solution to reduce the no. of includes in your code, so many includes may reduce speed.